# Continues To Hurt The Tool Owner (Roblox Studio)

Tags: lua, scripting, roblox

**I do not know if I am going to understand well, but my problem with this script is that I made a tool called SSGasterBlaster. What this tool basically does is spawn a Gaster Blaster, you know, like Sans. The GasterBlaster is a model, and the path of the script that I am going to pass is `StarterPack.SSGasterBlaster(tool).GB(model).Model(model).beam1(part). DebounceDamageBrick(damage script).` This last one is the damage script that has the problem.
So far, I have tried many ways to fix this issue. In the beam1 part, there are settings for the damage that the GasterBlaster does. Additionally, there is an ObjectValue called 'Owner' that is supposed to determine the owner of the tool and prevent it from being damaged. However, it does not work as expected. I don't know why it is not working despite my attempts to fix it. On the other hand, the ObjectValue 'Owner' does work and correctly detects the name of the player.
In short, the beam1 part is still hurting the owner, even though I didn't intend for it to do so. I am looking for help with the script:**

```
local c = script.Parent
local debounce = true

c.Touched:Connect(function(hit)
    local player = hit.Parent
    local Owner = script.Parent.Owner

    if player:FindFirstChild("Humanoid") and debounce then
        local isOwner = (player.Name == Owner.Value)

        if not isOwner then
            debounce = false

            local damage = script.Parent.Settings.Damage.Value

            if script.Parent.Settings.KR.Value then
                for i = 1, 10 do
                    hit.Parent:FindFirstChild("Humanoid"):TakeDamage(damage)
                    wait(0.01)
                end
            else
                player.Humanoid.Health = player.Humanoid.Health - damage
            end

            debounce = true
        end
    end
end)
```

*I have tried localscripts*

Comment: You just stuffed 204 words into a single sentence. Please work on your grammar, it's very hard to understand your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I made the code much simpler but I don't know if it works

```
local c = script.Parent


c.Touched:Connect(function(hit)
    local player = hit.Parent

    if not player:FindFirstChild("Humanoid") then return end
        local damage = script.Parent.Settings.Damage.Value
        if not player.Name == script.Parent.Owner.Value then
            if script.Parent.Settings.KR.Value then
                for i = 1, 10 do
                    hit.Parent:FindFirstChild("Humanoid"):TakeDamage(damage)
                    wait(0.01)
            else
                player.Humanoid.Health = player.Humanoid.Health - damage
            end
        end
    end)
```